# Detach JPA entity, detaches associated entities?

Tags: jpa, detach

Hy,

I have a JPA entity which I get from database and this entity has a few associations which are retrieved too from database; these associated entities are eager retrieved. My questions is:

1. If I detach the main entity (with EntityManager detach method)  which have these associations, are these associated entities detached too?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only associations which have `cascade=CascadeType.DETACH` will be detached when you detach an Entity.